# android content listing and footer

Tags: android, tabs

Hi 
I am an android user.  I have content listing page and i completed it successfully. But the problem is i have to put two tab on the footer and the footer tab should remain permanently. I also done so many searches to fix this issue bu cannot find the solution. Anybody please help me.

Thanks,
Anoop

Answer (score 0):

Do want to try to add header and footer to list view? then please check the addHeader in list view .check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29)

I have implement it,if need then i will post the code

Comment: Thanks for your help. can you please post your code this will really help me. I have post all my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242020/android-content-listing-and-footer-including-session

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a TabHost with the TabWidget underneath the FrameLayout inside a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout, as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <FrameLayout
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:padding="5dp" />
                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TabHost>
```